# seaborn "kde jointplot" doesn't have color mapping in the latest version (0.11.0)

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I was running `seaborn ver. 0.10.1` on my jupyter notebook. This morning I upgraded to the latest version `0.11.0`. Now, my kde jointplot doesn't give the color mapping that it used to. The code is the same. Only the versions are different.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

%matplotlib notebook

np.random.seed(1234)

v1 = pd.Series(np.random.normal(0,10,1000), name='v1')
v2 = pd.Series(np.random.normal(60,15,1000), name='v2')
v3 = pd.Series(2*v1 + v2, name='v3')

# set the seaborn style for all the following plots
sns.set_style('white')

sns.jointplot(v1, v3, kind='kde', space=0);
```

[image: Link to the image (This is my first question, I can't embed an image)]

Comment: Maybe the version upgrade made it non-supported. Please refer to [this release](https://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew.html).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The function `kdeplot` (which is used internally by `jointplot()`to draw the bivariate density plot) has been extensively changed in v.0.11. See [What's new](https://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew.html#changes-to-existing-functions) and [the documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html?highlight=kdeplot#seaborn.kdeplot).

You now have to pass `fill=True` to get a filled KDE, and you need to specify `thresh=0` if you want to fill the available space with color.

```
sns.jointplot(x=v1, y=v3, kind='kde', space=0, fill=True, thresh=0, cmap='Blues');
```

[image]